# How can I do this query in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
SELECT * 
FROM item_master 
WHERE project_id IN (SELECT id FROM project_master 
                     WHERE workspace_id in (SELECT id FROM workspace_master 
                                            WHERE company_id = 4));
```

How can I do this mysql query in sequelize - node js without using raw query?

Comment: you need to setup the relation first inside your models, and this tools can help you to create the query [Sequelize UI](https://sequelizeui.app/)

Comment: You can just use Model.FindOne or Model.FindAll methods. Additionally, if you don't want to write query as raw like this maybe, you also can use knex as the query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const item = await Item.findAll({
    where: {
        status: { [Op.ne]: 99 },
        '$project.workspace.company_id$': { [Op.eq]: req.user.companyId }
    },
    include: {
        model: Project,
        as: 'project',
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: {
            model: Workspace,
            as: 'workspace',
            attributes: ['id', 'companyId'],
            where: {
                companyId: req.user.companyId
            },
        },
    }
})
```

This is working as I want.

> '$project.workspace.company_id$': { [Op.eq]: req.user.companyId }

Comment: But what you asked in the question and comments are not same as compare to your answer. See your answer, why you have put `company_id` in two places? Your query is not looking optimized.

Answer (score 0):

If your model structure is like `item_master` has many `project_master`, and `project_master` has many `workspace_master`, then the following sequelize query will be applied with `async/await`.

As I edited my answer. As you said in comment, you have model structure like workspace has many projects and projects has many items. Then Sequelize query will be like:

```
    const getResult = async (workpace_id, company_id = 4) => {
      const result = await workspace_master.findAll({
      subQuery: false,
      include: [
        {
          model: project_master,
          as: 'project_masters', // this is your alias defined in model
          attributes: ['id','foo','bar'],
          include: [
            {
              model: item_master,
              as: 'item_masters', // this is your alias defined in model
              attributes: ['id','foo','bar']
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      where: {
         id: workspace_id,
         company_id: company_id
      }
    });
    
    if(!result || !result.length) return res.send('Something went wrong!');
    return res.send(result);
   }
```

Now try this, I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: My model structure is like workspace had many  project, project has many items

Comment: I guess the above answer make sense? If you need more help then please clarify.

Comment: using include will add both the table to the required result, tried reducing them with attributes, is there any alternative?

Comment: Yes then make `attributes:[]` empty in the `includes`, so you can reduce the attributes in the result.

Comment: Hi, while working out this query I got some results that were on other company id, just there wasn't any associated table

Comment: I have edited my answer, according to your model structure as you said in the comment section. Regards